# UI is rendered but screen is not painted unless touched

Tags: react-native

We are able to confirm that the `render()` method of our component is getting invoked. We also see that the data that needs to be shown is correctly passed in via props. However, the actual phone display won't repaint the updated UI until it is touched.

Interestingly this only happens in the production build not on the development builds of the app. Sigh.

We have seen this in the past when updates are done from `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions`, but in this case we have removed every use of `runAfterInteractions` and are still seeing this behavior.

Using react native 0.57 but also seeing the same issue on 0.58.

I can provide more specifics if needed, but wanted to know if anyone has seen anything like this before and what if anything they did to fix such an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a struggle, but I figured out what was happening.

TL;DR

The solution is to wrap your redux action dispatches inside a `setTimeout(..., 0)` whenever you are doing UI updates from a function passed to `runAfterInteractions` or from a Realm callback.

Some quick background:

I was dispatching a [redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux) action inside a [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) callback. The action would in turn cause the UI to re-render, except the rendered UI would not repaint on screen until it was touched.

Similar behavior was observed when you dispatch redux actions from a callback passed to `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions`. This makes sense because callbacks passed to `runAfterInteractions` wait for UI to do its thing and are then [executed as a `setImmediate` batch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager). These callbacks were intended for heavy background jobs that would otherwise block UI rendering. So if one were to do UI rendering in such callbacks those would themselves get halted like a background job!

Solution:

The point of the realm callback is to notify you that some data has changed, so that you can re-render your UI. However, the realm callback was behaving like one passed to `runAfterInteractions` and so UI re-rendering was getting held up. I took a leap of faith and decided to move the Redux action dispatching code to a different queue, namely `setTimeout`. Here's what the fix looked like:

```
... 
// assume this is in a callback passed to runAfterInteractions
// or in a realm callback

      // PUT YOUR REDUX ACTION DISPATCHES IN A setTimeout
      // callback
      setTimeout(() => {
        getFilteredCartAreas(dispatch, realm)
        dispatch(new ActionCartAreaCardChanged())
      }, 0)

...
```

The fix is to do the UI rendering logic inside a callback passed to `setTimeout`. Notice the zero delay; the goal is to simply move logic to a different queue that is not held up by UI interactions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. but I'm using Connect Parameter from Redux. `export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(OnbObjectiveScreen);`

ANy idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also when the content that should repaint was inside a 'ScrollView'. I refactored my code using a 'FlatList' instead of a 'ScrollView' and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was using a FlatList and tried all sorts of advice I read. I finally found out what was going on. Posting my answer shortly.